# Change default font in MathJax

Tags: mathjax

I wanted to change default font in MathJax into "Latin-Modern".

I edit file config/default.js and I put three changes in "HTML-CSS part":

```
availableFonts: [],
preferredFont: "null",
webFont: "Latin-Modern",
```

And Latin-Modern still doesn't appear. What I do wrong?

Comment: Try `null` not `"null"`. Otherwise, please post a full example.

Comment: Still no effect...  ` "HTML-CSS": {

    scale: 100,

    minScaleAdjust: 50,
    

    availableFonts: [],
    

    preferredFont: null,
    
    webFont: "Latin-Modern",
    
    imageFont: "Latin-Modern",
    
    undefinedFamily: "Latin-Modern,'Arial Unicode MS',serif",
 
    mtextFontInherit: false,

    EqnChunk: 50,
    EqnChunkFactor: 1.5,
    EqnChunkDelay: 100,

    matchFontHeight: true,

    noReflows: true,

    linebreaks: {
      
      automatic: false,

      width: "container"
    },

(...)`

Comment: I'd suggest to create a live sample (preferably using SO's snippets). Cf. http://codepen.io/pkra/pen/KbCyE

Comment: I wrote an email to You, please see Your mailbox :)

Comment: OK, I probably know where is problem... It is shown probably correctly, but I thought that it will be looks like "\mathsf"... Is it possible to make font from "\mathsf" as default font? @PeterKrautzberger